# How to lock drupal admin password?

Tags: mysql, database, drupal

I want to lock the admin(user 1)'s password. How could I do it in database level? Or How to lock the data row so that no one can change the data of that row in the database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend using the [paranoia](https://www.drupal.org/project/paranoia) module. It's one that prevents editing of the user 1 information as well as automatically taking care of some other risky permissions.